# How to iterate a forEach over an object/array/key values from axios in JS (make DRY)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, axios

I'm struggling to condense this code into one forEach loop to make my code dry. The image shows the console.log(res) for what I'm working with.

[image: imageForResponse]

Here is my code:

```
   .get('https://website.went.here/articles')
        .then((res) => { 
            const articles = res.data.articles;
            const js = articles.javascript;
            const bs = articles.bootstrap;
            const jq = articles.jquery;
            const node = articles.node;
            const tech = articles.technology;

            i = 0;

           console.log(articles.values(res));

            js.forEach((item) => {
                card.appendChild(cardCreator(item))
            });
            bs.forEach((item) => {
                card.appendChild(cardCreator(item))
            });
            jq.forEach((item) => {
                card.appendChild(cardCreator(item))
            });
            node.forEach((item) => {
                card.appendChild(cardCreator(item))
            });
            tech.forEach((item) => {
                card.appendChild(cardCreator(item))
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array of properties that you need to iterate over, iterate over those properties, and for each property, iterate over all elements in the property array and append:

```
.get('https://website.went.here/articles')
  .then((res) => {
    const { articles } = res.data;
    for (const prop of ['javascript', 'bootstrap', 'jquery', 'node', 'technology']) {
      for (const item of articles[prop]) {
        card.appendChild(cardCreator(item));
      }
    }
  });
```

Or, if you have to use `forEach`:

```
.get('https://website.went.here/articles')
  .then((res) => {
    const { articles } = res.data;
    ['javascript', 'bootstrap', 'jquery', 'node', 'technology'].forEach((prop) => {
      articles[prop].forEach((item) => {
        card.appendChild(cardCreator(item));
      });
    });
  });
```

If the order of the properties being appended doesn't matter, you can make it easier by simply iterating over the object values of the `articles` object:

```
.get('https://website.went.here/articles')
  .then((res) => {
    for (const arr of Object.values(res.data.articles)) {
      for (const item of arr) {
        card.appendChild(cardCreator(item));
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I appreciate giving the different options. The second one worked well, for me understanding the format was driving me crazy. I didn't realize it was okay to write it out "const arr of object.values" and looking at examples was making me so confused. You're wonderful, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get an object's keys.

For example,

```
const obj = {"javascript": [...], "python": [...], "bootstrap": [...]}
```

`Object.keys(obj)` will output `["javascript", "python", "bootstrap"]`.

From there, you can store that array as a variable, then iterate over those keys like so:

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.forEach(key => {
  obj[key]...
})
```